# How to sum between dates in a DataTable with multi conditions using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, date, datatable, sum

```
Name           issue_date      free_coupon_days category
Einstein       25/Dec/2015           60          movie 
Hellen Keller  01/Jan/2016            7          movie
Einstein       09/Jul/1999            9          movie
Einstein       14/Jun/2015            3          waterpark
Hellen Keller  19/Nov/1980           30          movie
Einstein       29/Sep/2015           19          movie
```

I have a DataTable dt, for example.

And I want to sum free_coupon_days with criteria as 'Eienstein', Date between '27/Sep/2015 ~ 27/Dec/2015', 'movie'.

The desirable output is **79** as calculated the rows as below.

```
Name           issue_date      free_coupon_days category    
Einstein       25/Dec/2015           60          movie
Einstein       29/Sep/2015           19          movie
```

I've tried some ways, but I'm beginner against complicated conditions.

This is some of the code I tried:

```
int sum_freecoupon_days_between_dates = (from item in dt
                                         where item.issue_date >= '27/Sep/2015' && item.issue_date <= '27/Dec/2015' &&
                                         item.Name == "Einstein" &&
                                         item.category == "movie"
                                         select item).Sum(k => k.free_coupon_days);
```

How can I do this in LINQ ?

Comment: If you want to use linq, then don't use `DataTable`.

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title.  They are not needed.

Comment: @LeiYang, I've been using LINQ on DataTable. There might be your point but I just need it in time-lacking situation.

Comment: also, you should put **minimal** code here, instead of your real project.

Comment: @Plutonix, I saw some questions in this way and I think only title is shown when we ask a new question if there're similar questions exist meaning title should contain category to avoid unmet needs..

Comment: See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)  The answer is *no*.  Most people use filters to restrict their view to the tags that interest them,  They are redundant in titles, just add noise and the space should be used to summarize the question

Comment: @Plutonix, Ok I agree. Could you kindly delete your 1 point comments? People are just commenting beyond the essence of the question, and now my question is full of someting looking like already done.

Comment: I dont know what a *1 point comment* is.  That code doesnt match the question though - it uses a date range relative to today, not the specific dates in the question text

Comment: @LeiYang, please don't say without reason. I showed the structure of table and desirable output but don't know the meaning of real project.

Comment: @Plutonix, it's just example..Ok I'll update right now..please don't mind my question.

Comment: @KayLee you'd better edit your code as column names as `A`, `B`, not `free_coupon_days`, just name a few.

Comment: Why do you think you need linq?  You could filter the DT and sum the resulting columns

Comment: @Plutonix, people can ask LINQ or not LINQ. but ok, then could you post an answer by filtering DT ? If it works, I'll mark as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I share my solution:

```
int sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Name") == "Einstein" &&                                                                                                           
                                        dr.Field<string>("category") == "movie" &&
                                       (dr.Field<DateTime>("issue_date").Date >= Convert.ToDateTime("27/09/2015") && dr.Field<DateTime>("issue_date").Date <= Convert.ToDateTime("27/12/2015"))).
                                        Select(dr => dr.Field<int>("free_coupon_days")).                                                         
                                        Sum();
```

Comment: Do you think `linq to DataTable` is elegant?

Comment: immature young boy, just mind yourself. do you think changing column name to A is elegant? Elegance is important? don't be kidding.

Comment: Did you know DataTable has a `Select` method and `DataColumn` has `Expression` property?

Comment: any more super opinions ?

Comment: If you don't care about elegant, why do you use linq instead of loop?